# Is there any order of columns while creating Hive table that needs to be pairtitioned dynamically?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to load an RDBMS table into Hive. I need to partition the table dynamically based on a column data. I have the schema of the Greenplum table as below:

```
forecast_id:bigint
period_year:numeric(15,0)
period_num:numeric(15,0)
period_name:character varying(15)
drm_org:character varying(10)
ledger_id:bigint
currency_code:character varying(15)
source_system_name:character varying(30)
source_record_type:character varying(30)
xx_last_update_log_id:integer
xx_data_hash_code:character varying(32)
xx_data_hash_id:bigint
xx_pk_id:bigint
```

When I checked for the schema of the same table on Hive (which is usually replicated on Hive), I did `describe extended tablename` and got the below schema:

```
forecast_id             bigint
period_year             bigint
period_num              bigint
period_name             string
drm_org                 string
ledger_id               bigint
currency_code           string
source_record_type      string
xx_last_update_log_id   int
xx_data_hash_code       string
xx_data_hash_id         bigint
xx_pk_id                bigint
source_system_name      String
```

so I asked my lead why is the `column: source_system_name` given at the end in Hive table and I got an answer: `"The columns that are used to partition the hive table dynamically, comes at the end of the table"`

Is it true that the columns on which the hive table is dynamically partitioned should come at the end of the schema ?

Comment: please, add the description and scripts used to insert the data, answer will depend on that but most probably yes..

Comment: `PARTITIONED BY` comes separately from the regular table columns, if that's what you mean

Comment: @hlagos I was preparing schema for the Hive table using Scala spark code. When I checked the order of columns, I noticed the above mentioned column order. Just wan to understand the concept and also what ever my lead told me was correct.

Comment: @cricket_007 I was not referring to 'PARTITIONED BY'. I checked the order of the columns between GP and Hive, noticed the difference.

Comment: @Sidhartha, the order of the columns matter in an insert operation where you are partition dynamically. Columns to be partitioned go at the end

Comment: @hlagos okay. Understood. How do I accept the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the columns matter when you are dynamic partition in Hive. You can find more details [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions). From the documentation

> In INSERT ... SELECT ... queries, the dynamic partition columns must
>   be specified **last** among the columns in the SELECT statement and in the
>   same order in which they appear in the PARTITION() clause.